# Remove low quality tag "Workplace Rythm"

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

By chance I noticed this rather odd tag: [workplace-rhythm](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workplace-rhythm)

I don't think this a useful tag; its certainly not a term I have ever heard used in the workplace.

Comment: Small note: there's special syntax for tags: `[tag:workplace-rhythm]`. Use `meta-tag` to link tags on meta.

Comment: @Lilienthal ty this was my first meta Q

Comment: This tag just makes me picture everyone dancing through the hallways at work.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, never noticed that one before.  I don't know what that means either.

There are currently 25 questions with this tag.  They'll need to be reviewed to answer these questions:

- Is there some other tag that all of these questions should have instead of this one?  If so, we can merge the tag into that other one.
- Does this tag add *zero value* and does every question also have at least one other tag?  If so, we can request that it be nuked, though at only 25 questions they might tell us to just delete it from the questions instead.  (If so, do that in a few batches, not all at once.)
- Is the answer different for different questions?  If so, those questions will need to be edited individually to adjust tags.

Comment: "*If so, do that in a few batches, not all at once?*" Why? Edit limits kick in after 4 or 5 questions but that just means you have to wait some time inbetween saving the edits. Do you mean to avoid saturating the updated question queue?

Comment: it avoids having the entire front page full of these. Every edit bumps to the front page

Comment: @Lilienthal yeah, I meant let's not flood the front page all at once and push out new (or newly-active) questions that haven't had a chance to draw attention yet.  If we keep it down to 8-10 at a time, or if people edit them when they come across them, we can clean it up without disruption.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ah okay. I don't ever use the front page myself, I always check the newest questions instead.

Comment: The front page is useful for seeing new answers come in.  Both views have their merits.

Comment: [tag:workplace-environment] or [tag:company-culture] seem viable candidates for most. I could only see two questions with only one tag: [Take your child to work day](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/490/take-your-child-to-work-day), and one where I'm genuinely sure which meaning of rhythm is intended: [Would listening to music be a good solution to avoid office keyboard sound](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42721/would-listening-to-music-be-a-good-solution-to-avoid-office-keyboard-sound)